# Embedding an Angular Directive in <tr>

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I'm trying to get an angular directive to repeat inside a `<tr>`. Without the directive, the code is

```
<tr *ngFor='let cluster of clusters'>
    <td style='display: flex; flex-direction: column; width: 40%; min-width: 300px;'>
        <span>{{ cluster.Name }}</span>
        <span>{{ cluster.StatusMessage }}</span>
    </td>
    <td style='width: 100%;'>
        ...
    </td>
</tr>
```

And looks like

[image]

When I refactor the directive, I lose the `<tr>` formatting. The refactored code is

```
<tr *ngFor='let cluster of clusters'>
    <cluster-row [name]='cluster.Name' [statusMessage]='cluster.StatusMessage'></cluster-row>
</tr>
```

The cluster-row component code is:

```
<td style='display: flex; flex-direction: column; width: 40%; min-width: 300px;'>
    <span>{{ name }}</span>
    <span>{{ statusMessage }}</span>
</td>
<td style='width: 100%;'>
    ...
</td>
```

It works, but the `<tr>` formatting goes away.

[image]

The developer tools show a `<tr>` with a `<cluster-row>` nested in it, and two `<td>`s nested in that, as I would expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<tr>` can't contain a `<cluster-row>` element.

You can use an attribute selector instead like

```
<tr *ngFor='let cluster of clusters'>
    <td cluster-row [name]='cluster.Name' [statusMessage]='cluster.StatusMessage'></cluster-row>
</tr>
```

with

```
@Component({
//@Directive({
  selector: '[cluster-row]'
```

The component or directive then **is** the `<td>`, therefore you can't repeat it inside the components template

```
style='display: flex; flex-direction: column; width: 40%; min-width: 300px;'
```

can just be added to

```
@Component({ 
  selector: '[cluster-row]',
  styles: [...],
```

Comment: Is this because a `<tr>` can only contain a `<td>`? I was hoping to be able to click the row to toggle different views, managed by the directive.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with " to click the row to toggle different views, managed by the directive". My answer is just about `<tr>` not supporting other children than `<td>`.

Comment: You can use `*ngIf` or `*ngSwitchCase` inside the component to display different content.

Comment: I think I was using "directive" when I meant "component." I'm learning Angular 2 after learning Angular 1.

Comment: I see. If that does what you want, this is perfectly fine as well.